# how to commit changes in aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that edit the content of an aspx page. But the aspx file didn't change at all. I want the aspx file content is also edited automatically.
Here is the function :

```
    protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        content.InnerHtml = content.InnerHtml + "<br/> <h3>" + headertambahan.Text + "</h3> <p p style=\"font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;\">" + isitambahan.Text + "</p>";
    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the content ? (literal, textbox, what ?)

Comment: "content" is an id of a div tag.
my code is succesfully changed the page. but when the page is redirected, the page is back to it's original. The changes are not permanent.

Comment: You now have totally change your question. Now you say that the page is change, but when is reloaded the content go back to the original text and this is normal. You do not have understand what you really do there. You are NOT programming the aspx page, you are not the visual studio, you only change one parameter. To keep that change you need some kind of database.

Comment: I see. Maybe it's because I'm not good in english that my question become unclear. So, is there any other way without using database?

Comment: If you want to keep track of something on a per-session basis without storing anything in a database, you want to look at ASP.Net's session state.  Here are some links to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6ad7zeeb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/03sekbw5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to either:

1) Make sure the button is causing a postback. Without a postback, no changes will be shown. You can ensure this by checking the properties of your button. **Note:** If you're using `asp:Button` this will cause a postback by default. If you're using something else for the click event you'll need to set the property `AutoPostBack="true"`.

2) You could wrap your `content` object in the markup in an `UpdatePanel`, and in your button cick call the `.Update()` method on your `UpdatePanel`, but that feels like it's probably overkill for what you're doing here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to consider using a `literal`.  Here's an example from W3Schools that, if I understand your question, accomplishes exactly what you are trying to do:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_literal2

Also - remember to use `runat="server"`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you call a javaScript function on your button click handler that will update your DOM element.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="content">
    <p>This is nothing</p>
</div>

<asp:Button ID="AddContent" runat="server" OnClick="AddContent_Click" />
```

**JS   :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeContent(headertambahan, isitambahan)
    {
        $('#content').html($('#content').text() + "<br/> <h3>" + headertambahan + "</h3> <p style=\"font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;\">" + isitambahan + "</p>");
    }
</script>
```

**Server Side :**

```
protected void AddContent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "ChangeContent('" + headertambahan.Text + "','" + isitambahan.Text + "');", true);
}
```

------------------- **Solution : 2** *(Question Updated Later)*

***For Permanent Change into your file :***

Update the particular section of your page with your desired content. Try this,

**HTML :**

```
<div id="content">
    <p>This is nothing</p>
    <p id='updateBox'></p>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="FileContentUpdate" runat="server" OnClick="FileContentUpdate_Click" />
```

**Server Side :**

```
protected void FileContentUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = @"F:\Stackoverflow\24099577\DomManipulation.aspx";
    string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; i++) 
    {
        content[i] = content[i].Replace("<p id='updateBox'></p>", "<br/> <h3>" + headertambahan.Text + "</h3> <p style=\"font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;\">" + isitambahan.Text + "</p>");
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, content);
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, but nothing happen. Besides, my code is succesfully changes the content of "content" but the changes are not permanent.